# MySQL, numero de linhas numa tabela com valores de outra tabela

Tags: mysql

hoje tenho uma pergunta se calhar um pouco básica mas o meu mysql ta um pouco enferrujado.

tenho 2 tabelas uma com os nomes dos users é outro com uma lista de mensagens
e queria saber quantas mensagens tem cada user.

tabela `users`

```
id | username
-------------
1  | joao
2  | nuno
3  | rui
```

tabela `mensagens`

```
id | msg  |user
------------------
1  | msg1 | joao
2  | msg2 | joao
3  | msg3 | nuno
```

o resultado que pretendo (por ordem de numero de mensagens)

```
user | msg_count
-------------
rui  | 0
nuno | 1
joao | 2
```

Comment: esqueci um pormenor, queria que se o valor `msg` na tabela `mensagens ` não tiver conteúdo a linha não fosse contabilizada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Faça uso de subselect para isso.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de SQL para te ajudar:

```
SELECT username as user, (SELECT count(1) as qtd FROM mensagens WHERE mensagens.user = users.username) as msg_count FROM users ORDER BY msg_count ASC
```

Comment: Obrigado @Hiago Souza é mesmo isso ;)